# Remove duplicates from an unsorted singly linked list causing logical error while trying to skip the repeated element

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I used auxiliary data structure "HashSet" to solve this problem. The logic is that I created a HashSet with non-repetitive elements and then while going through each node in my linked-list, checked if that item is in the hashSet. If it is there, I removed the data from the HashSet iterated through the linked list. The code and the logical error should be pretty self explanatory. I am just not able to skip the element in the list for the linked list that I have created in the main method.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

class Node{
    int value;
    Node next;

public Node(int value){
    this.value = value; 
    next = null;
}
public Node deleteNode(Node headNode){
    Node current = headNode;
    HashSet<Integer> setContainer = new HashSet<Integer>();
    while (current.next != null){
        setContainer.add(current.value);
        current = current.next;
    }
    current = headNode; // reset current to the headNode

    while (!setContainer.isEmpty()){
        if (current.next == null){
            return headNode;
        }
        if (current == headNode){
            setContainer.remove(current.value);
            current = current.next;
            //System.out.println(setContainer); Test
            continue;
        }
        if (!setContainer.contains(current.next.value)){
            current.next = current.next.next;
            current = current.next;
        }
        else{
            setContainer.remove(current.value);
            current = current.next; 
            //System.out.println(setContainer); Test
        }
    }
    return headNode;
}
public void printList(Node head){
    Node current = head;
    while(current.next != null){
        System.out.println(current.value);
        current = current.next;
    }
}}
```

This is the main method

```
public class mainTester {
    public static void main (String[] args){        
        Node node = new Node(10);
        node.next = new Node(20);
        node.next.next = new Node(12);
        node.next.next.next = new Node(11);
        node.next.next.next.next = new Node(10);
        node.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(20);
        node.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(30);
        node.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(30);
        node.printList(node);
        System.out.println("\nLets see how it goes");
        node.deleteNode(node);
        node.printList(node);
    }
}
```

The output after implementing deleteNode came as 10,20,12,11,20,30 which is not as expected. Please help correct this logical issue.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Which line? What's the expected output?
This information would make it much easier to solve your issue without having to run your code.

Comment: If you are looping from head to tail there is no need to cache the set values.

Comment: Emptying the cache is what is causing the problems. By the time you hit the second 20 in the list it was removed from the cache by the first one in the list. If this solves the problem I will post it as an answer

Comment: You should also loop through the length of the list. If the are duplicates, the size of the set will always be less than the length of the list

Answer (score 2):

The error in your logic is after finding a duplicate, you are skipping to the next node after that without checking if that is a duplicate. You can fix this by changing

```
if(!setContainer.contains(node.next.value)) {
```

And just removing the second line

```
current = current.next
```

Also: You should be looping until current == null, not when setContainer is empty, as you could miss duplicates for instance if the same number was repeated twice at the end

Comment: His logic does not find duplicates. He is deleting items from the set.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I did if(!setContainer.contains (current.value)) and as per your suggestion removed that second line. It worked but I am not quite clear why it did. So when 10 is current which is not in HashSet, we are skipping over 20 and setting 30 as the next node right ? So it was quite unclear. Can you please explain why it worked?

Comment: After moving the third in line node to replace the second, you need to check with the same current Node again to see if the new second node is a duplicate

Comment: @efekctive read the question and my answer again. As OP states, my answer fixes the bug with removal of duplicates

Comment: I am verifying that now because he is deleting from the set if the value exists. This does make much sense. Caching the set does not make sense either

Comment: @ControlAltDel Can you please help me clear one confusion. So whenever we sense that its a duplicate, we did current.next = current.next.next by which the next node for 10 is 30. So by this how did 10 got skipped from being printed ? I hope I was clear. I apologize for my amateurism, I am just learning these data structures in my algorithms course.

Comment: @ShrijanAryal I am sorry I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

This is a more compact/efficient version of the logic that does not erase data

```
class Node{
    int value;
    Node next;

public Node(int value){
    this.value = value; 
    next = null;
}
public Node deleteNode(Node headNode){
    Node previous = null, current = headNode;
    HashSet<Integer> setContainer = new HashSet<Integer>();
    current = headNode; // reset current to the headNode

    while(current != null){
        if (!setContainer.contains(current.value)){
            setContainer.add(current.value);
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        else{
            previous.next = current.next;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return headNode;
}
public void printList(Node head){
    Node current = head;
    do{
        System.out.println(current.value);
        current = current.next;
    } while(current != null);
}}
```

The out put it generates with :

```
 Node node = new Node(10);
            node.next = new Node(20);
            node.next.next = new Node(12);
            node.next.next.next = new Node(11);
            node.next.next.next.next = new Node(10);
            node.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(20);
            node.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(30);
            node.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(30);
            node.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(20);
            node.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(30);
            node.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(40);
            node.printList(node);
            System.out.println("\nLets see how it goes");
            node.deleteNode(node);
            node.printList(node);
```

is

```
10
20
12
11
10
20
30
30
20
30
40

Lets see how it goes
10
20
12
11
30
40
```

Comment: I get the part where you have made previous to trail current. So when current is at 10 (the second 10 in my LinkedList), the previous is at 11. The set does contain 10, so you have set previous.next as 20 and current as 20.  But how did we skip over 10 ? Please can you shortly explain this else code-block ?

Comment: If current is already in the set, then it can't be previous's next. Make current's next previous's next and continue; The loop can be improved by turning it into a do loop. Because if the new current is last but it is repeated it will not be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

```
private ListNode<Integer> removeDuplicate(ListNode<Integer> head) {
    Set<Integer> container = new HashSet<>();
    if (head == null) {
        return head;
    }
    ListNode<Integer> prev = head;
    ListNode<Integer> temp = head.getNext();
    while(temp != null) {
        if (container.contains(temp.getValue())) {
            prev.setNext(temp.getNext());
        } else {
            container.add(temp.getValue());
        }
    }
    return head;
}

public class ListNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
private T value;
private ListNode<T> next;

public ListNode(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    next = null;
}

public T getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public ListNode<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(ListNode<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}
}
```